# Python Image Library fails to read HDFS path

Tags: python, image-processing, pyspark, hdfs, tiff

I am trying to read a '**.tif**' image which is of [m,n,4] (rows, columns, channels) dimension with '**uint16**' data type from **HDFS** in **PySpark** using libraries like '**tifffile**' using the following code:

```
import tifffile as tiff\ img = tiff.imread('hdfs://master:9000/image1.tif')
```

, but I always get the message:

---

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/user/spark_files/tfos/hdfs:/master:9000/image1.tif'`.

---

The HDFS path of the image `hdfs://master:9000/image1.tif` is correct and 'tifffile' lib works well when using the local file system instead of HDFS.
It looks like the image library does not understand HDFS paths!
How to solve this considering Spark API can't read this kind of image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I could solve this problem using `hdfs` and `imagecodecs` libraries:

```
from pyarrow import hdfs
import imagecodecs

connect = hdfs.connect("master",9000)
img_file = connect.open('/img1.tif', mode='rb')
img_bytes = img_file.read()
numpy_img = imagecodecs.tiff_decode(img_bytes)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can solve this in two ways

1. Spark-submit your job and pass the required files using --files option, in this way it will be uploaded to all the executors and can be accessed directly.
2. Get you file on edge node and then trigger the script.

Comment: The problem is not providing Spark with image files, but in reading these files and offering them as Numpy arrays.
I can easily copy my images to HDFS and PySpark can see them but can't read them as images
Could you please show me an example code that works here?

Comment: If you are running your spark application in client mode, then the driver stays at edge node itself which requires you to copy your image from hdfs to edge node first then run your script, this way numpy will be able to access the file as if it is present locally,

Comment: You mean to copy my images from HDFS to the local file system of the edge node, after that reading them using an image library, and finally providing them as an argument while submitting my Spark job, right?